# File exists in mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have one directory where I am keeping multiple files. 
File name - backup-input.txt
I want to check whether this file is exist or not at my location.
I am new to Mulesoft.
Could anyone suggest correct way to do this?

I didn't find any solution with File component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an Expression Component and set the expression to something like:

```
flowVars.myFiles = new File("C:\\MyFiles\\Adoc.txt");
```

then

```
flowVars.myFiles.exists()
```

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/expression-component-reference

Comment: But if file is not present, File component doesn't work. In my case my starting point is File component.

Comment: Mule's File CONNECTOR is explained here https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/file-connector . It looks in the specified location for you and passes the file as the message's payload. Your question reads like you want to check the existence of an arbitrary file.